# How to mask the boundary only and neglecting the inner portion of an image(a donut shaped mask)

Tags: python, image-processing, mask, contour, scikit-image

I'm working on image processing wherein I got the contours of my image but the problem is when I go on visualizing it masks the inside area as well...thinking of a **donut** I only want the outer boundaries to have a mask and not the inner part...I have made use of `measure.find_contours()` function here.
Can someone plz help me with this one?

The original png looks like this:
[image: im1]
The required area I want my mask on(just the border width and nothing else)
[image: im2]

```py
contours = measure.find_contours(img.sum(-1), 0.5)
print(contours, 'contours')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

for contour in contours:
    ax.plot(contour[:, 1], contour[:, 0], linewidth=2)

ax.axis('image')
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Bilal i have added the images for better understanding.

Comment: i just want the mask over my black border and nothing else

Comment: @Bilal okay so, what if i send the original png (first pic) and an image mask of the same which has only 2 colors white and black(2nd pic)...now what you are saying is i go on and have an mask over the outer boundary of some width based on the pixel info?? is it?? If so, then till now according the requirement of the detectron2 i had my custom dataset which i somehow made according to the pycoco format making use of segmentation and contours..how am i suppose to find out the pixel based mask now? would that info be enough to create a mask which currently requires a couple of things?

Comment: @arizona_3 This is possible using OpenCV. Did you get your result?

Comment: @JeruLuke are you by any chance inclining towards edge detection?

Comment: @arizona_3 No, I thought of finding the largest contour and filling it using cv2.fillPoly(). In that way the donut hole would be covered and you would get your expected result

Comment: @JeruLuke i see will try doing that!! seems like a good idea..

Comment: @JeruLuke but what if there are multiple boundaries/strokes and moreover dashed strokes will what you are saying work for that? i doubt

Comment: Sharing related images will help